# What is the difference between forall a. [a] and [forall a. a]?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

Title and tags should explain the question adequately.

Comment: Even if the question is self-explanatory, it's nice to have a small example in the body.

Comment: What would you suggest, Josh?

Answer (score 20):

> Title and tags should explain the question adequately.

Err, not really.  You used the tag `existential-type`, but neither of the types you gave is existential.

### System F

There's already some good answers here, so I'll take a different approach and be a bit more formal.  Polymorphic values are essentially functions on types, but Haskell's syntax leaves both type abstraction and type application implicit, which obscures the issue.  We'll use the notation of [System F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F), which has explicit type abstraction and type application.

For example, the familiar `map` function would be written

```
map :: ∀a. ∀b. (a → b) → [a] → [b]
map = Λa. Λb. λ(f :: a → b). λ(xs :: [a]). case xs of
  [] → []
  (y:ys) → f y : map @a @b f ys
```

`map` is now a function of *four* arguments: two types (`a` and `b`), a function, and a list.  We write a function over types using Λ (upper-case lambda), and a function over values using λ as usual.  A term containing Λ gives rise to a type containing ∀, just as a term containing λ gives rise to a type containing →.  I use the notation `@a` (as in GHC Core) to denote application of a type argument.

So a value of polymorphic type is like a function from types to values.  The caller of a polymorphic function gets to choose a type argument, and the function must comply.

### ∀a. [a]

How, then, would we write a term of type `∀a. [a]`?  We know that types containing ∀ come from terms containing Λ:

```
term1 :: ∀a. [a]
term1 = Λa. ?
```

Within the body marked `?` we must provide a term of type `[a]`.  That is, a term of type `∀a. [a]` means "given any type `a`, I will give you a list of type `[a]`".

However, we know nothing concrete about `a`, since it's an argument passed in from the outside.  So we can return an empty list

```
term1 = Λa. []
```

or an undefined value

```
term1 = Λa. undefined
```

or a list containing undefined values only

```
term1 = Λa. [undefined, undefined]
```

but not much else.

### [∀a. a]

What about `[∀a. a]`, then?  If ∀ signifies a function on types, then `[∀a. a]` is a list of functions.  We can provide as few as we like:

```
term2 :: [∀a. a]
term2 = []
```

or as many:

```
term2 = [f, g, h]
```

But what are our choices for `f`, `g`, and `h`?

```
f :: ∀a. a
f = Λa. ?
```

Now we're well and truly stuck.  We have to provide a value of type `a`, but we know nothing whatsoever about the type `a`.  So our only choice is

```
f = Λa. undefined
```

So our options for `term2` look like

```
term2 :: [∀a. a]
term2 = []
term2 = [Λa. undefined]
term2 = [Λa. undefined, Λa. undefined]
```

etc. And let's not forget

```
term2 = undefined
```

### Existential types

A value of universal (∀) type is a function from types to values.  A value of existential (∃) type is a *pair* of a type and a value.

More specifically:  A value of type

```
∃x. T
```

is a pair

```
(S, v)
```

where S is a type, and where `v :: T`, assuming you bind the type variable `x` to `S` within `T`.

Here's an existential type signature and a few terms with that type:

```
term3 :: ∃a. a
term3 = (Int,         3)
term3 = (Char,        'x')
term3 = (∀a. a → Int, Λa. λ(x::a). 4)
```

In other words, we can put any value we like into `∃a. a`, as long as we pair that value with its type.

The *user* of a value of type `∀a. a` is in a great position; they can choose any specific type they like, using the type application `@T`, to obtain a term of type `T`.  The *producer* of a value of type `∀a. a` is in a terrible position: they must be prepared to produce any type asked for, so (as in the previous section) the only choice is `Λa. undefined`.

The *user* of a value of type `∃a. a` is in a terrible position; the value inside is of some unknown specific type, not a flexible polymorphic value. The *producer* of a value of type `∃a. a` is in a great position; they can stick any value they like into the pair, as we saw above.

So what's a less useless existential?  How about values paired with a binary operation:

```
type Something = ∃a. (a, a → a → a, a → String)

term4_a, term4_b :: Something
term4_a = (Int,    (1,     (+)  @Int , show @Int))
term4_b = (String, ("foo", (++) @Char, λ(x::String). x))
```

Using it:

```
triple :: Something → String
triple = λ(a, (x :: a, f :: a→a→a, out :: a→String)).
  out (f (f x x) x)
```

The result:

```
triple term4_a  ⇒  "3"
triple term4_b  ⇒  "foofoofoo"
```

We've packaged up a type and some operations on that type.  The user can apply our operations but cannot inspect the concrete value — we can't pattern-match on `x` within `triple`, since its type (hence set of constructors) is unknown.  This is more than a bit like object-oriented programming.

### Using existentials for real

The direct syntax for existentials using ∃ and type-value pairs would be quite convenient.  [UHC](http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/UHC) partially supports this direct syntax.  But GHC does not.  To introduce existentials in GHC we need to define new "wrapper" types.

Translating the above example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Something = forall a. MkThing a (a -> a -> a) (a -> String)

term_a, term_b :: Something
term_a = MkThing 1 (+) show
term_b = MkThing "foo" (++) id

triple :: Something -> String
triple (MkThing x f out) =
  out (f (f x x) x)
```

There's a couple differences from our theoretical treatment.  Type application, type abstraction, and type pairs are again implicit.  Also, the wrapper is confusingly written with `forall` rather than `exists`.  This references the fact that we're declaring an *existential* type, but the *data constructor* has *universal* type:

```
MkThing :: forall a. a -> (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> String) -> Something
```

Often, we use existential quantification to "capture" a typeclass constraint.  We could do something similar here:

```
data SomeMonoid = forall a. (Monoid a, Show a) => MkMonoid a
```

### Further reading

For an introduction to the theory, I highly recommend *[Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/)* by Pierce.  For a discussion of existential types in GHC, see [the GHC manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#existential-quantification) and [the Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_type).

Comment: Hooray, System F! Side-note for anyone else reading this: those capital lambdas up there are why my analogy of `forall` to a lambda expression makes any sense. They even have pretty much the same scoping rules (extend all the way to the right, unless enclosed in parentheses). This stuff is exactly how I read type signatures in my head these days and I'm glad keegan spent the time to write this.

Comment: @keegan  This is such a rigorous answer. Thanks for this :) !!!

Answer (score 6):

The type `forall a. [a]` means that for any single type, it's a list containing that type. This is also what just plain `[a]` means and is the type of `[]`, the empty list data constructor.

The type `[forall a. a]` would mean that you have a list of values with polymorphic type, that is, each one is a value of any possible type, not necessarily the same as other elements of the list. No possible value can have the type `forall a. a`, so this must also be an empty list.

The difference, then, is that while the first can be used as a list of any type (by definition, basically), the latter can't be used as a list of any concrete type at all, since there's no way to pin it down to any single type.

To address the tag--an existential type is one that, within some scope, will be instantiated to some unknown concrete type. It could be anything, so is represented by something like the `forall a. a` above. To make sure that anything with an existential type is only used within the scope where the actual type will be available, the compiler prevents existential types from "escaping".

It may help to think of the `forall` quantifier as being like a lambda expression--it introduces a new type variable and binds that identifier within some scope. Outside that scope, the identifier has no meaning, which is why `forall a. a` is pretty useless.

Comment: I can think of one value with type `forall a. a`, namely `⊥`.

Comment: @John: Well, yes, but I hesitate somewhat to call ⊥ a "value". As an aid to learning, though, I think questions of "type theory as applied to Haskell" are better considered in a fictitious realm of only total functions, the presence of ⊥ mostly being a distraction from such matters. Besides, it's poor taste to discuss bottoms in polite company. ;)

Comment: I disagree.  I think it's better to provide the complete story up front rather than "almost true" statements, because then when the issue does come up it's more work to unlearn than it would have been to get it right from the beginning.  That may just be my learning style bias of course.  Although I do sometimes wish for a fictitious Haskell without `seq`.

Comment: @John: My thinking is that it's easier to learn the complete story with ⊥ included if you understand some type theory, and that it's easier to learn type theory as a Haskell programmer if you ignore ⊥. A fair amount of the mathematical theory used in Haskell only works "properly" when ignoring ⊥ anyway...

Answer (score 4):

When used for types `forall` means intersection. So `forall a. a` is the intersection of all types or something like `Int ∩ String ∩ ...` which seems to give the empty set but each type has an extra element called bottom or ⊥ or `undefined` in Haskell. From this we get that `forall a. a = {⊥}`. Actually we can define a type which contains only bottom:

```
data Zero
```

After this setup lets look at our types starting with `[forall a. a]`. What it defines is a list of bottoms or `[Zero]` which has elements `[], [undefined], [undefined, undefined], ...`. Lets check it in ghci:

```
> let l = [undefined, undefined]::[Zero]
> :t l
l :: [Zero]
```

In a similar way `forall a. [a]` is the intersection of all list types and since `∩[a] = [∩a]` this is again `[Zero]`.

To do a final check lets define:

```
type L = forall a. [a]
type U = [forall a. a]
```

and in ghci:

```
> let l2 = [undefined, undefined]::L
> let l3 = [undefined, undefined]::U
> :t l2
l2 :: [a]
> :t l3
l3 :: U
```

Notice that `l2::[a]`, the explanation is that Haskell puts an implicit `forall` in front of all polymorphic types.