# Are the real Type of Polymorphic Types in Haskell implicitly universally quantified Type?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to clarify some Haskell concepts. When defining a type through data declaration such as:

`data DatumType a b = Datum a b`

I have been wondering if the type is `DatumType` or **implicitly** `forall a. DatumType a b`.

Because indeed with **ExplicitForAll**

```
λ> :set -XExplicitForAll
λ> :k forall a. Maybe a
forall a. Maybe a :: *

λ> :k forall a b . DatumType a b
forall a b . DatumType a b :: *

λ> :k DatumType
DatumType :: * -> * -> *
```

We can see that the kind `forall a b. DatumType a b` is `proper type i.e. *`

DatumType however in itself is just a Type Constructor.

Hence this would mean that **polymorphic type** such as [a] are TYPE (i.e. *) and that the full name of the type is `forall a. [a]`

In other word, what i am after is to confirm that type declaration in Haskell for **polymorphic type** are always in an abbreviated form, and that the full type name is always with an implicit `forall a. ....`

That is, in `data Mytype a` the type is not `Mytype` neither just `Mytype a`, but `forall a. Mytype a`, while `Mytype` is a type constructor.

Is that interpretation correct ?

## EDIT1 (following @Daniel Wagner Answer)

I think I will edit the question, to explain where the all thingy of clarification is coming from. Let’s just say that while learning and experimenting with type classes, I was confused about instance Eq (a,b). Why not instance Eq (,), and the answer is not just because one need to refer to the type variable in the implementation. Eq can only be defined on a proper type, and any possible pair is actually a type, a polymorphic type. Then came the question, but what are we defining when we write data (,) a b = (,) ab . Am I defining (,) or forall a b. (a,b).

## Edit2 (Following @Ben Answer)

One of the material that drove my formalisation together with the
`:set -XExplicitForAll` experiment above is the following statement taken from here [A Gentle Introduction to Haskell, Version 98 - 2  Values, Types, and Other Goodies](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/goodies.html#:%7E:text=Haskell%20also%20incorporates%20polymorphic%20types,type%20of%20lists%20of%20a.)

> Haskell also incorporates polymorphic types---types that are universally quantified in some way over all types. Polymorphic type expressions essentially describe families of types. For example, (forall a)[a] is the family of types consisting of, for every type a, the type of lists of a. Lists of integers (e.g. [1,2,3]), lists of characters (['a','b','c']), even lists of lists of integers, etc., are all members of this family.

Comment: Hi Maat. I have fixed this spelling error a number of times for you already. When you say "trough", you mean "through". A trough a long open container, usually used for serving food to farm animals. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition `data DatumType a b = Datum a b` translated into English is something like this:

Let there be a new type constructor named `DatumType` and a new data constructor named `Datum` such that for all types `a` and `b`, `Datum` applied to a value of type `a` and a value of type `b` results in a value of type `DatumType a b`.

> I have been wondering if the type is `DatumType` or **implicitly** `forall a. DatumType a b`.

I think the barrier to understanding here is that the term "type" can have two different meanings, depending on context:

1. A **type** is any entity that exists at type-level
2. A **type** is specifically those type-level entities that can serve as the type of terms; anything in the kind `Type` (which is also called `*`), and only such things

These two definitions basically arise because we use the phrase "type of" to describe the relationship between things on the term level and things on the type level - so it seems odd to include things that can't participate in that relationship in the meaning of "type". And yet there are plenty of things that exist in type expressions that cannot participate in that relationship directly, we want to talk about them without having to use clunky phrases like "type level entity" all the time. As a community, we don't seem to have come up with a better solution than just using "type" in both of those senses at different times, and hopefully being clear from the context.

So it's clear that `DatumType` is not a type by definition 2; it needs to be applied to two type parameters to result in a type of something at the term level. If that's what we're thinking then I can see why you would lean towards thinking "the type" defined by the data declaration is `forall a b. DatumType a b`.

However I think that's probably a confusing way to think about it. Taken on its own `forall a b. DatumType a b` is the type of terms that could be used in **all** types of the form `DatumType _ _`; the only values in this type are things like `Datum undefined undefined`. Rather the `forall a b` will normally be further out when you see `DatumType a b`; for example the type of the `Datum` constructor itself (which is what you'd write if you were defining it using GADT syntax) can be written as `Datum :: forall a b. a -> b -> DatumType a b`.

So saying "the type defined by the data declaration is `forall a b. DatumType a b` is pretty weird. The data declaration defines a whole *family* of types, of which the type `forall a b. DatumType a b` is one extremely limiting (and fairly useless) example. Rather I would say "for all types `a` and `b`, the data declaration defines a type `DatumType a b`"; the scope of the "for all" concept involved is wider than you can express with a `forall` keyword in a single type expression, so I moved it out of the formal type expression to the English description.

Of course if we focus on definition 1 of "type", then things are *much* simpler to explain. The data declaration simply defines a type `DatumType` with kind `* -> * -> *`.

This invites the question: which view is *correct*?

Perhaps unsatisfyingly, there is nothing interesting going on between these two viewpoints. *Both* of those things happen: we get a new type constructor `DatumType` that has kind `* -> * -> *`, and for all types `a` and `b` `DatumType a b` is a type of some terms. That's what a thing of kind `* -> * -> *` *means*. The dilemma only arises when you try to identify "*the* type" without realising that the term type is frequently used in both these two senses, so if you're not clear with yourself on which sense *you're* using you can trip up.

Some contexts say that things which don't have kind `*` are not types, and therefore `DatumType` is not really a type. Others talk about `DatumType` as a type. However that is purely a difference in what terminology we choose to use; either way `DatumType :: * -> * -> *` is a thing that exists, and it functions the same in either viewpoint. Getting hung up on whether a particular type-level entity is or is not a type is *not* a question of how things really work, it's just a question of English language usage.

So to come back to some of your more specific questions:

> Hence this would mean that **polymorphic type** such as `[a]` are TYPE (i.e. *) and that the full name of the type is forall a. [a]
>
> In other word, what i am after is to confirm that type declaration in haskell for **polymorphic type** are always in an abbreviated form, and that the full type name is always with an implicit `forall a. ....`

As I mentioned, I think this is not quite correct. Yes, `[]` at the type level needs a parameter to result in a type-of-terms; `[] :: * -> *`. So by definition 2, `[]` is not a type. However it's not really right to say that the full list type is "really" `forall a. [a]`, as that is a specific type expression for universally polymorphic lists (which can only be the type of empty lists, or of lists full of bottom values, or a list that *is* the bottom value). In particular, `[True, False]` is a member of the type `[Bool]`, and is **not** a member of the type `forall a. [a]`.

Rather `[]` is just a type-level-entity of kind `* -> *`. whether you call that a type or not is up to you. Either way it is not the type of any terms, and either way it is a valid thing you can use in type expressions (provided they kind-check).

> That is, in `data Mytype a` the type is not `Mytype` neither just `Mytype a`, but `forall a. Mytype a`, while `Mytype` is a type constructor.

It is true that `Mytype` is a type constructor. (In either definition of the word "type"; even if we're happy to call all type-level entities types, "type constructor" is still a specific category, and it's a good term to have because whether something is a "type constructor" cannot be determined just by looking at its kind, in the same way that you can't determine whether something is a data constructor just by looking at its type)

It is true that `Mytype a` **on its own** is not meaningful; it has to be used in a scope where a type variable `a` is in scope.

It is not true that `forall a. Mytype a` is the right way to think of "the type defined by `data Mytype a`. For *any* type `a` `Mytype a` is a type; `forall a. Mytype a` is a *specific* type expression that does not include most of the types we can form with the `Mytype` type constructor.

So any time you want to use `Mytype a` there will be a `forall` somewhere (either explicit or implicit). But it will usually be further out than immediately enclosing `Mytype a`; something like `someFunc :: forall a. a -> Bool -> MyType a`.

---

The OP left a comment on the other answer which I think it will be insightful to address:

> I think I will edit the question, to explain where the all thingy of clarification is coming from. Let’s just say that while learning and experimenting with type classes, I was confused about `instance Eq (a,b)`. Why not `instance Eq (,)`, and the answer is not just because one need to refer to the type variable in the implementation. `Eq` can only be defined on a proper type, and any possible pair is actually a type, a polymorphic type. Then came the question, but what are we defining when we write `data (,) a b = (,) a b` . Am I defining `(,)` or `forall a b. (a,b)`.

Keep in mind that making a type an instance of `Eq` is intended to mean that you can compare *values* of that type for equality.

When you say `instance Eq (a, b)` it really means `instance forall a b. Eq (a, b)`; in English "for all types `a` and `b`, the type `(a, b)` is a member of the class `Eq`. It means you can pick any two types you like, apply the `(,)` type constructor to them, and the resulting type will be something use values you can compare for equality. (This is of course not actually true, the instance we really use is more like `instance forall a b. (Eq a, Eq b) =>  Eq (a, b)`, because we need `Eq a` and `Eq b`)

`instance Eq (,)` is wrong because it is saying "the type constructor (,) is a member of the class `Eq`". "Values of `(,)` can be compared for equality" makes no sense, as `(,)` is not the kind of thing that can have values.

But `(,)` is still a thing that exists! And it's straightforwardly the thing defined by `data (,) a b = (,) a b`. It's just a thing with kind `* -> * -> *`, which is not the kind of thing we can make an `Eq` instance for. The phrase "`Eq` can only be defined on a proper type" is using the definition of "type" that only includes things with kind `*`, but remember "not being a proper type" by this definition does not mean "isn't a real thing", it just means we're choosing (in that particular sentence, at least) to use the word "type" with a narrow meaning. The class `Eq` is *defined* to have as members things with kind `*`, that's all. Other classes can be defined to have things with different kinds as members; if they have members of kind `* -> * -> *` then `(,)` on its own can be an instance of those classes. Have a look at the list of instances for [`Bifunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#t:Bifunctor), for example. The fact that the `Eq` instance has to be `Eq (a, b)` and not `Eq (,)` does *not* imply that `(,)` isn't "really" a valid entity that exists at the type level.

Comment: Thank Ben, this is really helpful. I will further wrap my head around it and get back. However already accepted because just by doing two passes on it, I feel less confused already :) !

Comment: Hm, perhaps haskell is conceptually harder to learn because the `forall` is implicit.

Comment: @Abastro For vanilla Haskell, I tend to think it's not harder. If I was explaining Haskell to someone who was *never* going to need to learn of any extensions, I probably wouldn't even introduce the concept of `forall` binders; just the general concept of universal quantification and "that's just how type signatures work". But if you're going to use any of the many extensions that use the forall keyword, then I tend to think it would have been easier to have it explicit and mandatory from the beginning; so yes, in that sense implicit `forall` makes things a bit trickier.

Comment: I mean, for beginners the type signature itself could be intimidating. Perhaps being more explicit would help the beginners comprehend what is going on.

Comment: Great discussion. IMO we should move away from calling everything on the type-level “type”, especially since `Type` is now the preferred name for the kind that used to be written `*`. Often it makes sense to put the distinction as _compile-time values_ vs _runtime values_. Types are a specific example of compile-time value. Incidentally terms are also only a specific example of runtime value – for example, consider something like `main = do {x <- readFile "foo.txt"; ...}`: the value of `x` does not correspond to any term in the Haskell language.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ahhh, I like compile-time vs. runtime. I have been trying to work out unambiguous and correct terms to distinguish the two for quite a while. The "type-level"/"term-level" never really worked for me, since there are terms at both levels. Using "types" vs. "values" never sat well because value is a technical term for a specific kind of term. I tried "type-level"/"computation-level" for a while, but that doesn't really work, either, since with the amount of extensions we have these days there can be plenty of computation at the type level. Compile-time/runtime feels just right.

Comment: @DanielWagner yes. Pity that _compile-time value_ is quite a mouthful. Perhaps shorten to “comtvals” and “runtvals” or something similar?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yeah, terminology is tricky. I used to use "values" and "value-level"; lately I've been switching to term-level out of a sense that "value" wasn't quite general enough. There can be terms in bits of code that will never run (even that **can** never run, with things like `absurd`) but the terms in the code still have types even though there's never a runtime value. Maybe it's just that both terms in our code and values at runtime are things that can have types, and they don't have to both be examples of a single concept?

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, compile-time value vs runtime value is very nice way of thinking for a lot of purposes. But what happens when we get more dependent type features: are we going to have runtime values that serve as the type of something? Is the identification of type-level things with runtime-erased things essential, or just a coincidence of our current system? And the same problem arises one level up of course; there are kind-level entities that are not kinds (in the strict sense that they are the kinds of any types), but kinds and types are both compile time values. :/

Comment: Maybe we just use something like t-vals for type-level-values, and then reserve "type" for things of kind `Type`. That suggests `k-vals` too, if we need them; I'm unsure if the identification of kinds with types in modern GHC internals means we don't actually ever need the concept of "the kind level" any more (conceptually; I know it isn't needed technically).

Comment: @Ben Of course when things get more complicated, things will get more complicated. Perhaps at that time I'll switch over to something like "universe 0, universe 1, universe 2" for what are currently runtime, compile-time, and kind.

Comment: @Ben I believe i am fully on the verge of having your answered sinked in :) !!! Just to confirm, i think it is that statement that does not help on one side (see update): Haskell also incorporates polymorphic types---types that are universally quantified in some way over all types. Polymorphic type expressions essentially describe families of types. For example, (forall a)[a] is the family of types consisting of, for every type a, the type of lists of a. Lists of integers (e.g. [1,2,3]), lists of characters (['a','b','c']), even lists of lists of integers, etc., are all members of this family.

Comment: That statement if I understand you well is flatly technically very misleading. "(forall a)[a]" in itself as you explained is not what the authors suggest here. List of Integer or Char and what not. Maybe it is an old literature as well. The POSITION of "forall" matters. Or more precisely as @Daniel Wagner was attempting to explain to me the other response, the Scope matters.

Comment: Alright finally got it. I understand now why all expression of the Type `forall a. MyType a` have no inhabitant. If anyone interested, this was thanks to a good System F explanation found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961851/what-is-the-difference-between-forall-a-a-and-forall-a-a :) !!! The "english" on this one was just not cutting it. That close the deal for me, thanks all for your help.

Comment: @MaatDeamon Yes, I think perhaps a better way of putting it is that polymorphic data declarations are *parameterised* rather than universally quantified. Universal quantification is more straightforwardly a feature themselves rather than of data types.

Comment: @MaatDeamon "A feature of type expressions, rather than of data types", that was supposed to be. Sorry for the confusing error.

Comment: Oh well, I still think you did a marvelous explanation. Yes it is not officially part of data declaration but to some degree it is implicit as well. Your 1st sentence in English ties it to the signature (type expression that comes with the data constructor of the data declaration/definition). I think it is the literature as I posted above which because of the need of simplifying what they are talking about, create some unintended confusion due to the lack of precision. Given the number of questions around the subject, I believe it is also just an aspect of Haskell, that is not well introduced

Comment: But yeah, I understand and like the accuracy of parameterized !

Answer (score 3):

The declaration

```
data DatumType a b = Datum a b
```

declares *one* new type, `DatumType`, of kind `* -> * -> *`. It also declares *one* new term, `Datum`, of type `forall a b. a -> b -> DatumType a b`.

Under normal circumstances, it is true that type signatures implicitly universally quantify all the type variables they mention at the top level. But a data declaration is not a type signature, so some parts of your question don't make sense.

It is also possible, with extensions turned on, for a type variable to be monomorphic, not universally quantified. For example,

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

foo :: forall a. Monoid a => a -> a
foo x = mconcat xs where
    xs :: [a]
    xs = [x, mempty, x]
```

In this code snippet, all quantifiers have been made explicit. Inside the where block, `xs` has the monomorphic type `[a]`, where `a` is a type variable bound by an enclosing typing scope, and if you inserted an extra quantifier the code would not compile:

```
foo :: forall a. Monoid a => a -> a
foo x = mconcat xs where
    xs :: forall a. [a]
    xs = [x, mempty, x]
    -- type error: can't match type a and type a0, whoops
```

With this information, hopefully the truth status of each of your statements is more clear, but let's walk through them one at a time:

> I have been wondering if the type is `DatumType` or **implicitly** `forall a. DatumType a b`.

Unanswerable. The type of what? Both `DatumType` and `forall a. DatumType a b` are legal type-level expressions.

> This would mean that **polymorphic type** such as [a] are TYPE and that the full name of the type is `forall a. [a]`.

Sometimes. The insertion of quantifiers is not a local process, but global to an entire type signature. They are implicitly floated up to the top level. So, these are two different types:

```
-- these are all the same with ScopedTypeVariables off
forall a. [a] -> ()
forall a. ([a] -> ())
[a] -> ()

-- this is a different type from the ones above
(forall a. [a]) -> ()
```

So if, in normal, un-extended Haskell, you wrote the type signature `x :: [a]`, then `[a]` would indeed be shorthand for `forall a. [a]`; but if you wrote the signature `f :: [a] -> ()`, then `[a]` would *not* be shorthand for `forall a. [a]`, because the `forall` has to be floated out from being on an argument to the arrow to being on the entire type.

> In other word, what i am after is to confirm that type declaration in haskell for **polymorphic type** are always in an abbreviated form, and that the full type name is always with an implicit `forall a. ...`.

Yes.

> That is, in `data Mytype a` the type is not `Mytype` neither just `Mytype a`, but `forall a. Mytype a`, ...

Category error. `data Mytype a` is not a type signature, so there is no *the type*. If I were to single out a type to call "the type" from such a declaration, it would be `Mytype` alone, as that is the only type that gets created by the declaration.

> ...while `Mytype` is a type constructor.

Yes.

Comment: Do you make a difference between a polymorphic type and a higher kinded type ? How do you create one or the other  ?

Comment: My guess is  you create a polymorphic type, and part of the polymorphic type include the definition of a higher kinded type ?

Comment: If a data definition include the definition of a type and its value, then that type must be a proper type, and the only proper type i see is the polymorphic type, which is concrete, the higher kind type can't have value.

Comment: Found an interesting post on the subject here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57085678/which-is-a-polymorphic-type-a-type-or-a-set-of-types

Comment: @MaatDeamon Yes, polymorphic types and higher-kinded types are different. A polymorphic type is one that begins with a `forall` (whether implicitly or explicitly); a higher-kinded type is one with an arrow in its kind. Examples of each combo: the `f` in `Applicative` constraints is typically poly+high, the type of `mempty` is poly+first-order, `[]` is mono+high, `[Int]` is mono+first-order. I don't understand the questions about creation. 1/?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "proper type" -- perhaps, one of kind * (or TYPE if you prefer)? Taking that assumption: it is not correct that the new type must be of kind *. It is true that new parameterized types are not inhabited by computations; the computation-level constructor produces a value of a type that mentions the new type by applying it to arguments. 2/2

Comment: Yes you guessed right about proper type. It is in the literature, but Haskell has it as * or TYPE. The term is not commonly used in Haskell corners.

Comment: I think I will edit the question, to explain where the all thingy of clarification is coming from. Let’s just say that while learning and experimenting with type classes, I was confused about `instance Eq (a,b)`. Why not `instance Eq (,)`, and the answer is not just because one need to refer to the type variable in the implementation. `Eq` can only be defined on a proper type, and any possible pair is actually a type, a polymorphic type. Then came the question, but what are we defining when we write `data (,) a b = (,) ab` . Am I defining `(,)` or `forall a b. (a,b)`.

Comment: @MaatDeamon I edited a bit into my answer to address what you've said in your last comment. Have a look and see if it helps!

Comment: @MaatDeamon I believe I answered that directly, right? You are defining `(,)`. (Quote from my answer: "The declaration `data DatumType a b = Datum a b` declares one new type, `DatumType`". `DatumType` is essentially just another way of spelling `(,)`.)

Comment: Yes I appreciate your answer and thanks for taking the time on this. You said the right things there, but Ben took the time to address my confusion, as in understanding where I was coming from and trying to start from there and  help me pass my limitation. Hence I accepted his.

Comment: I like the putting things in « English », it is my style 

Comment: @DanielWagner Just want to thank again, i did my readying and understand better your explanation, i just did not have the background to understand it properly. Learning about ScopedTypeVariables, XTypeApplications, fprint-explicit-foralls and a bit of -XRankNTypes or basic System-F helped following you :)

Comment: @MaatDeamon Sounds like a pretty impressive reading list! I'm glad you found resources that got you where you needed to go.