# how to universally quantify Reified Type Class instance when scraping your type class in haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Studying the infamous blog post [scrap your type classes](https://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html), for the sake of learning, but  in particular to understand the meaning of `forall` in type class instance declaration as stated here [Explicit universal quantification (forall)](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/explicit_forall.html)

> As well as in type signatures, you can also use an explicit forall in an instance declaration:
>
> instance forall a. Eq a => Eq [a] where ...

This  is generally in the backdrop of me refining my understanding of `forall` in haskell, where among other i have learned how to be careful of its scope.

Hence to make things explicit I have been trying to reproduce the [scrap your type classes](https://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html)  appraoch for the following use case:

```
data  DatumType a b = Datum a b deriving Show

instance forall a b . (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (DatumType a b) where
  (==) (Datum x y) (Datum z e) =  x == z && y == e
```

renaming Eq as Same, i.e. but declared as

```
data Same a = Same {
  (===) :: a -> a -> Bool
}
```

However I get stuck here as I do not see how to write the instance with the forall a b

```
SameDatumTypeab :: ???
SameDatumTypeab =  Same {
 -- ???
}
```

Could any one help with this ? is this even possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing you couldn't have come up with some trial and error...

```
sameDatumTypeab :: ∀ a b . (Eq a, Eq b) => Same (DatumType a b)
sameDatumTypeab = Same {
   (===) = \(Datum x y) (Datum z e) -> x==z && y==e
 }
```

As usual, the forall is optional (variables that appear are implicitly universal-quantified at the outermost level), i.e. you can simply write

```
sameDatumTypeab :: (Eq a, Eq b) => Same (DatumType a b)
sameDatumTypeab = Same $ \(Datum x y) (Datum z e) -> x==z && y==e
```

But actually that's kind of missing the point of Scrap Your Classes, because I'm now *using* the `Eq` class though I'm not instantiating it. To make it fully class-free, we want to also convert the `(Eq a, Eq b)` constraint:

```
sameDatumTypeab :: Same a -> Same b -> Same (DatumType a b)
sameDatumTypeab (Same eqa) (Same eqb)
   = Same $ \(Datum x y) (Datum z e) -> eqa x z && eqb y e
```

FTR, the typeclass instance also doesn't need to be explicitly quantified

```
instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (DatumType a b) where
  Datum x y == Datum z e = x == z && y == e
```

Comment: thanks will play with that indeed. Just for the record, i am using forall explicitly because i am still learning it. I was blocked indeed because, as far as i have learned in stack overflow and through test `x :: forall a. a` or `list:: forall a. [a]` are variable that can only be satisfied by bottom i.e. respectively `undefined` and `undefined or []`. Hence i am surprised  that  the above does not lead to the same, what am i missing ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961851/what-is-the-difference-between-forall-a-a-and-forall-a-a

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57085678/which-is-a-polymorphic-type-a-type-or-a-set-of-types

Comment: Answer was actually missing some important things, see now.

Comment: Ok i see, so we have `forall a b. Same a -> Same b -> Same (DatumType a b)` which make more sense to me.