# Clarifying Universal quantification over Haskell Record

Tags: haskell, record

We know that

```
forall a. a -- undefined
forall a. [a] -- [] or undefined
forall a. (a,a) --  undefined
```

However i have noticed that

```
data Record a where -- GADTSyntax eq. to data Record a = Record { idx :: a -> a }
  Record :: forall b. {idx :: b -> b } -> Record b

record :: forall a. Record a
record = Record { idx = \x -> x }  -- Not undefined
```

That is `record :: forall a. Record a` is not undefined as in the above. I suspect it is because it is a record of functions, but that does not explain really why with respect to the rule of the type system this is ok.

The above first quantification are well explained here:

- [What is the difference between forall a. [a] and [forall a. a]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961851/what-is-the-difference-between-forall-a-a-and-forall-a-a)
- [Which is a polymorphic type: a type or a set of types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57085678/which-is-a-polymorphic-type-a-type-or-a-set-of-types)

Hence I wonder if anyone can provide some "somewhat" "formal" (type system perspective explanation) clarification of how is that possible i.e. what is actually happening ? How is GHC actually handling it ?

Comment: I want to understand the reason why you find that surprising. Do you expect that a polymorphic definition having signature `x :: forall a . something something ...` must only involve undefined values. Your last example is a wrapped form of `id :: forall a . a->a ;  id x = x` -- what's surprising about that?

Comment: Coherence, understanding how the type system work. When i learn a language, i don't learn it syntactically as a set of construct that works here and there, but i semantically, i.e. what am i saying/meaning when i write this or that. I have found very  useful in the past. I have started learning haskell for that reason. Especially given that other language (my main language is not haskell) use  thingy that i find well articulated in haskell. I was in search of a language well grounded in a coherent theory, not set of constructed taken from here and there.

Comment: The very fact that i see something like `record :: forall a. Record a` and do not get it straight a way is a sign that i am not well grasping certain things, and i am trying to overcome that.

Comment: To be  more  concrete the all motivation came from things like `instance  forall a b. (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (a,b)` while i was trying  to understand forall, and not understanding what it means. I have used it of course, but as a construct to  do  what i  needed to  do, but  without understanding why there was a `forall` implied in such a type  of instance declaration. It did not fit any of the understanding i had about `forall`. Indeed it felt like i  am defining the Eq of a Type that has no inhabitant. Then digging into how type class are implemented, it landed me here.

Comment: Hope the motivation and journey make sense and that you can actually help me get where i am trying to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We know that
>
> ```
> forall a. a -- undefined
> forall a. [a] -- [] or undefined
> forall a. (a,a) --  undefined
> ```

Yes, but also these:

- `forall a. [a]` contains:

  1. `undefined`
  2. `[]` (fully defined)
  3. `undefined : xs` for any `xs`:

  - `undefined : []`, a.k.a. `[undefined]`
  - `undefined : undefined : undefined`
  - `undefined : undefined : []`, a.k.a. `[undefined, undefined]`
  - (And so on.)
- `forall a. (a, a)` contains no fully defined terms:

  1. `undefined`
  2. `(undefined, undefined)`

> However i have noticed that
>
> ```
> data Record a where -- GADTSyntax eq. to data Record a = Record { idx :: a -> a }
>   Record :: forall b. {idx :: b -> b } -> Record b
>
> record :: forall a. Record a
> record = Record { idx = \x -> x }  -- Not undefined
> ```
>
> That is `record :: forall a. Record a` is not undefined as in the above.

That’s right. `forall a. Record a` contains the terms:

1. `undefined`
2. `Record undefined`, a.k.a. `Record { idx = undefined }`
3. `Record id`, a.k.a. `Record { idx = id }`, which is a defined value

> I suspect it is because it is a record of functions, but that does not explain really why with respect to the rule of the type system this is ok.

Not exactly. `GADTSyntax` gives the type of the constructor explicitly, which is a good starting point to understand this. We have:

```
Record :: forall b. { idx :: b -> b } -> Record b
```

Or, without the record notation, and with some extra parentheses and a `KindSignatures` annotation for good measure:

```
Record :: forall (b :: Type). ((b -> b) -> Record b)
```

That is to say, if you apply the data constructor `Record` to any `Type` argument of your choosing, then it will be assigned to the type parameter `b` and substituted into the type `(b -> b) -> Record b`. For example, with `Int`:

```
forall b.    (b   -> b  ) -> Record b
(b ~ Int) => (b   -> b  ) -> Record b
             (Int -> Int) -> Record Int
```

(NB. `~` is an equality constraint; this syntax is enabled by the `GADTs` or `TypeFamilies` language options.)

This parallels how a lambda/function expression receives an argument value for its parameter:

```
(\  i ->      i + 3)
let i =  2 in i + 3
              2 + 3
```

In fact, `forall` is the type-level analogue of a lambda, it just takes and produces types rather than values.

So, after applying `Record` to a type `b`, if you apply the result to a function `f :: b -> b` which accepts and returns values of *that particular type* `b`, then you can construct a value of type `Record b` (here, the type constructor `Record`). Normally, the application of type arguments is implicit, but you can make it explicit with the `TypeApplications` language option:

```
Record            :: forall b. (b   -> b  ) -> Record b

Record       not  ::                           Record Bool

Record @Int       ::           (Int -> Int) -> Record Int

Record @Int (* 2) ::                           Record Int
```

Now, in the polymorphic case, `record :: forall a. Record a`, you’re saying that anyone is free to supply `record` with any type `a` that they choose (such as `record @Char`) and they’ll get back a value of type `Record a` (being `Record Char` if `a` = `Char`). Except for the extra `Record` wrapper, this is the same as promising to construct `T -> T` for *each* possible type `T`, and in the general case, that’s promising `T -> T` for *all* `T`, because `record` doesn’t demand any further information constraining its type parameter, like `Num a` or `Ord a`.

With the `ScopedTypeVariables` language option, you can annotate the fact that, inside the body of `record`, there’s a particular type variable called `a`, whose value is *unknown* to you, but nevertheless *constant*.

```
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}

-- ‘forall’ defines the scope of ‘a’.
record :: forall a. Record a

-- ‘a’ refers to the above ‘a’, not a new one.
record = Record { idx = \ (x :: a) -> x }
```

Or:

```
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}

record :: forall a. Record a
record = Record { idx = f }
  where
    -- Again this would normally mean a fresh ‘a’,
    -- but here it refers to the scoped ‘a’.
    f :: a -> a
    f x = x
```

> Hence I wonder if anyone can provide some "somewhat" "formal" (type system perspective explanation) clarification of how is that possible i.e. what is actually happening ?

Another way to think of this is that, if a type contains only terms that can be fully evaluated to values, then interpreting that type as a logical formula (by the [Curry–Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence)) will produce “true”, i.e. it will be a tautology; if it’s “false”, then a term of that type must crash or loop in *some* cases, like `head []`, but not necessarily *all* cases, like `head [1]`. You can look at this very mechanically:

- `Void` has no values, since it has no constructors. This corresponds to “false”. It contains only one term, `undefined`.
- `()` has one defined inhabitant for its one constructor, and corresponds to “true”. It also contains the term `undefined`.
- `Either A B` is inhabited by `Left (x :: A)` and `Right (y :: B)`, if either `A` or `B` (or both) are inhabited. It contains `undefined`, `Left undefined`, and `Right undefined` as well.
- `(A, B)` is inhabited by `(x :: A, y :: B)` if both `A` and `B` are inhabited. It contains `undefined`, `(x, undefined)`, `(undefined, y)`, and `(undefined, undefined)` too.
- `A -> B` is inhabited if it can construct a value `y :: B` for each value `x :: A`.
- `forall (x :: A). B` is inhabited if it can construct a value `y :: B` for each *type* `x :: A`, where `A` is a kind, like `Type`, `Type -> Type`, &c.
- Other types can be expressed as (possibly  recursive) combinations of these primitive ones.

So for example `forall a. a` is false, because if you interpret it as a logical expression (“for all A (true or false), A is true”) then it obviously has a counterexample (“false is true” is nonsense).

`forall a. Record a` (or just `forall a. a -> a`, without the wrapper) are inhabited because you can always produce `Record id` (resp. `id`). Logically this is saying “for all A, A *implies* A”, which is the case: truth implies truth, and falsehood implies anything (a.k.a. *ex falso quodlibet*).

Likewise, `forall a. [a]` is inhabited because you can always produce `[]`. In detail, this is the logic formula “L(A) = for all A, true or A and L(A)”, which is always true, derived by unrolling `[a]` into `Either () (a, [a])`, with `()` corresponding to `[] :: [a]`, and `(a, [a])` corresponding to `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`).

Comment: Amazing answer, very thorough, thank you for this !!!!

Comment: I understand it all, and your answer is overall super well articulated and appreciated the logical statement too. However, the only thing that i do not understand, or does not feel right to me, is `forall (x :: J). (Y :: K) is inhabited if it can construct a type Y :: K for each type x :: J (where J and K are kinds, like Type, Type -> Type, &c.).` I'm not really sure what was the intent on this one.  If it was supposed to help understand `forall a. a`, i am not sure this is right.

Comment: In short you explained clearly, that it is about being able to have a value of a specific type, and `for all a. Record a`, yes can have a value. A value for `forall a. Record a`, is essentially a value for `forall a. a -> a`.  Indeed the GADT syntax makes it clear: ` Record :: forall b. {idx :: b -> b } -> Record b`

Comment: This being said, I think that when it comes to `forall a. a` the System-F based explanation explain it better. The type signature`∀a. a -> b` has term value `Λa.λ(x:a).x`, or `/\(a :: Type) -> \(x :: a) -> x`, but what is a term value for `∀a. a` ?  `/\(a :: Type) -> ???`.  We know no nothing about a, it is a type variable, so if anything, we know it represents all possible type, and what is a possible value for all possible type ? I guess it is "Undefined".

Comment: @MaatDeamon: Ah yeah that explanation was poor/unfinished, updated a little.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if:

```
data Record a where
    Record :: forall b. { field :: Whatever b } -> Record b
```

for an arbitrary type function `Whatever`, then `forall a. Record a` will be inhabited (by a non-bottom value) if and only if `forall a. Whatever a` is inhabited.

This shouldn't be too surprising.  This single field ADT creates a polymorphic isomorphism between `Record b` and `Whatever b` through the functions `Record` and `field`:

```
Record :: forall b. Whatever b -> Record b
field :: forall b. Record b -> Whatever b
```

and the rules of rank-2 types allow the following isomorphism -- between the inhabitants of `forall a. Record a` and `forall a. Whatever a` -- to type check:

```
toRecord :: (forall a. Whatever a) -> (forall a. Record a)
toRecord = Record

fromRecord :: (forall a. Record a) -> (forall a. Whatever a)
fromRecord = field
```

Note that the field doesn't need to be a function.  Given:

```
data Record1 a where
    Record1 :: forall b. { field1 :: [b] } -> Record1 b
```

the type `forall a. Record1 a` is isomorphic to `forall a. [a]` and is inhabited by `Record1 []`.

Maybe that helps?

Comment: Yes it does.  Will wrap my head around it. Thanks

Comment: It did help, but given my background and how fluent i am with haskell type system it  took me some time to understand it all. Sorry but i must admit i had the re-read the definition of isomorphism and review rank-2 to understand the proof.

Comment: This being said i think you when you wrote `forall a. Record1 a` is inhabited by `Record1 []`, you meant to say `Record1 { field1 = []  }`.

Comment: Field names are optional in Haskell, so the expressions `Record1 []` and `Record1 { field1 = [] }` are equivalent.